# Saving images in Document Directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am downloading images from web in uitableview and want to save in document directory. I am downloading syncronously. I downloaded and saved in document directory successfully, but when i scroll uitable every time images are being saved , i want to save images at the time of downloading only once. What should i do? Can anybody provide me some code? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should **never use synchronous download**. It will block your UI, make your UITableView scrolling lag, make the user think your app has frozen... Very bad idea.

You should instead always use asynchronous download using `NSURLConnection`'s `loadRequest:` method and implementing the delegate methods yourself (even probably dedicate a class to manage the download, as everybody do)

[See the LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) sample code from Apple Documentation, it explains how to load images asychronously to display them in a TableView, loading them on demand, and avoiding to freeze the UI.

**Never do blocking operations** in the delegate methods of UITableView like `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (and I hope you use the reuse-mechanism of UITableViewCells correctly too, to reduce cell allocations. See the TableView Programming Guide about this point)

Once you have implemented the asynchronous download using NSURLConnection and its delegate methods, its a piece of cake to move the code that saves the images in the documents folder in the `connectionDidFinishLoading:`  delegate method (thus saving them only once and only when they are downloaded)

Comment: Thanks Ali i have solved app frozen problem the images are successfully saving in directory but my problem is that each time i scroll table the same images are being saved again and again.

Comment: Do as I suggest by moving the code that save the image in the NSURLConnection delegate method to save them only when downloading the first time (hope you don't redownload the images each time?!)

Comment: @suhail You will need to set up a cache of sorts. Quick and easy make a dictionary of the image web requests and before sending out any request check for that key in the dictionary. If its there just load the file from documents. You may need a more durable solution for caching depending on how many images you expect to see but this works well for simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

Do the saving of images in didConnectionFinishLoading method. You can also use an NSNotification for this, to know when the download is getting completed.
Hope this information is useful.